# Is there anything wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is there anything wrong with [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370399/what-differentiates-function-objects-from-poltergeists)? Can it be fixed or should it for any reason be deleted?

[Edit] The question talks about high-level concepts that are relatively common and well-known. It provides links to descriptions of the two concepts. Lack of research on the part of the asker is not the problem here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important)

Comment: also possibly related: [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking a question like "why is X different from Y", the very minimal thing I would expect from any asker on this site is to present his thoughts, arguments and research **why he thinks** that X is different or (maybe not different) from Y.

Otherwise such a question could invite to a broad discussion, people guessing around what the asker was thinking, and there willl probably no right answer. And this is exactly what SE does not want to be - this site is not a discussion forum, it is a Q&A site.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this could be a the problem and I'll think about how I can revise the question without instigating further discussion. I was actually about to include my thoughts at the time of writing, but erased almost everything in favor of being clear and sussinct, as well as humble - "if I say what I think the answer is, why am I asking"-kind of thing.

Comment: I modified the question. If you have time, could you please look over it?

Comment: @GregKramida: looks much better now. After such a huge edit, however, you check if the answers you already got still match your question, and if not, leave a comment for the answerers.