# Question deleted even though there are similar questions on the site

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I fond similar questions on the site, so decided it was the right place to ask it here. I have provided those questions in the comments. And the question was not just closed, it was deleted by a moderator, so I cannot ask for undeletion and cannot expect someone to even comment...

Why isn't it good for this site if there are similar questions already asked?

[image]

Similar questions:

[Are there standard practices when writing a spec for a software development project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118231/are-there-standard-practices-when-writing-a-spec-for-a-software-development-proj)
[What is the standard for modeling modern applications prior to development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80974/what-is-the-standard-for-modeling-modern-applications-prior-to-development)

Comment: The scope of this site has changed over the years, in 2011 it was much broader. See [this meta answer of mine](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9180/9113) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of similar questions that have not been closed and/or deleted does not mean that a particular question is a good fit for the site. We have definitions of [what topics are appropriate to ask about here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (which includes questions that appear to fit into topics but are not a good fit) as well as [the types of questions that should not be asked here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions should be compared to these descriptions of this site's scope and not to other questions.

Specifically, [questions asking for references or resources are not permitted](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487).